# Reize div content to 100%

Tags: html, css

I am trying to resize the contents of two div based on what device the user has pc,tablet,phone with various resolutions.

I use this css code for the contents of my first div to align it left 80%.

```
.id1
{
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    max-width:100%;
    min-width:80%;
    margin-right:20px;

}
```

for my second div tag which includes a sidebar i use the following css code

```
.id2
{
    position: relative !important;
    min-width:100px;
}
```

when the width of the sidebar turn below 100px it automatically aligns itself at the bottom.

but i need to change the width of my first div to 100% ... how can i change it when the 2nd div automatically aligns itself at the bottom? Is this possible using css?

Comment: Please use Media Queries for responsiveness.

Comment: # Mobile
only screen and (min-width: 480px)

# Tablet
only screen and (min-width: 768px) 

# Desktop
only screen and (min-width: 992px)

# Huge
only screen and (min-width: 1280px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use media-query. Something like that:

```
@media (max-width: 576px) { /* if device is mobile */
  .id1
  {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:100%;
    min-width:80%;
    margin-right:20px;
  }
}
```

Comment: why max-width:576px for mobile?